# Process run / start behaves differently in 'flutter run' and directly running a built app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop, dart-io

I'm using `Process.run()` / `Process.start()` to open tensorboard in my flutter app on macos. A weird problem is everything goes well when I directly run the flutter app on the connected device (by using `flutter run` or `flutter run --release`). But when I use `flutter build macos` or `flutter build macos --release` and then open the built app, the app will collapse when I trigger the `Process.run()` / `Process.start()` command.

For further experiments, I tried setting `runInShell` to be true and this time the built app won't crash but still I cannot open tensorboard.

I doubt if the different behavior is because the father process of these two running ways is different. So is there a way to run the command in flutter as if using the terminal to do so?

Comment: Checkout this answer, probably resolves your issue.https://github.com/tekartik/process_run.dart/issues/36#issuecomment-1210019411

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Though I didn't write flutter at present, I'm glad to know there is a solution. If this is a valid solution, you may also comment under my previous git issue (https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89837) so more people can see the solution. It has been labelled as a P4 bug, but I don't think the flutter team has the time to fix it.